# Remove the first par of bracket from an Array Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this array with double pairs of bracket [["0": 5, "2": 10]] and I want to convert it to ["5","10"] or [5,10]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What you have right now is a dictionary inside of an array as its only element. This is probably not the data model you want. Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let dict = [["0": 5, "2": 10]]
let dict0 = dict[0]
var array: [Int] = []
array.append(dict0["0"]!)
array.append(dict0["2"]!)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. We're just extracting the dictionary values and creating an array. If you had a long list you could put your dictionary through a for-loop.

```
    let dictionary = [["0": 5, "2": 10]]
    let array = [dictionary[0]["0"]!,dictionary[0]["2"]!]
    print("array: \(array)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve here. But this solution does exactly what you asked in your question. i.e. convert an `Array` of `Array` of `Dictionary` into an `Array` ( [["0": 5, "2": 10]] -> [5,10] )

```
let data = [["0": 5, "2": 10]]
var finalArray = Array<Any>()
for dictArr in data {
    for (key,value) in dictArr {
        finalArray.append(value)        //[5,10]
    }
}
```

If you want to convert an `Array` of `Array` of `Dictionary` into an `Array` of `Array` of `Element` ( [["0": 5, "2": 10]] -> [[5,10]] ), use the following code.

```
let data = [["0": 5, "2": 10]]
var finalArray = Array<Any>()
for dictArr in data {
    var tempArr = [Int]()
    for (key,value) in dictArr {
        tempArr.append(value)
    }
    finalArray.append(tempArr)        //[[5,10]]
}
```